# Spring Security Role Based Authorization is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm implementing Spring Security in a demo Spring Boot project, I have implemented the following Spring Security Authorization for the URLs. But, I'm unable to access the `GET APIs` with the `MANAGER` and `ADMIN` roles. Also, when I try to access the `DELETE API` with the `ADMIN` role, I get `403 Forbidden`. I'm  not sure what the issue is.

```
@Configuration
public class DemoSecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager()
    {
        UserDetails john = User.builder()
            .username("john")
            .password("{noop}test123")
            .roles("EMPLOYEE")
            .build();

        UserDetails mary = User.builder()
            .username("mary")
            .password("{noop}test123")
            .roles("EMPLOYEE, MANAGER")
            .build();

        UserDetails susan = User.builder()
            .username("susan")
            .password("{noop}test123")
            .roles("EMPLOYEE, MANAGER, ADMIN")
            .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(john, mary, susan);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer->
            configurer
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/employees/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        );
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf(csrf->csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know very little of spring security, but `.roles("EMPLOYEE, MANAGER, ADMIN")` why comma separated entries in a single string? [looking at the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.UserBuilder.html#roles-java.lang.String...-) shouldn't that be a list like: `.roles("EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER", "ADMIN")`